# Rails dry-validation passed when params missing and rise an error when it's present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry-validation

In my Rails 7 app I want to use dry-validation gem to validate incoming JSONs inside `create` method of my `MandateController`. Basically based on that JSON request:

```
  "sdd_setup_request": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
    "data": {
        (...)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to validate it using that validator class:

```
  params do
    required(:sdd_setup_request).schema do
      required(:return_url).value(:string)
      required(:data).hash do
       (...)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But still gets an error of `sdd_setup_request is missing`, when I change it to `optional` inside the validator class it will be passed. But then when I want to test if the other validations work and remove `return_url` form the JSON file I should get an error of missing `return_url` but the validation will pass instead.

Nothing fancy inside of the controller class:

```
class MandatesController < BaseController
  def create
    result = SddRequestValidator.call(params)
    if result.success?
     (...)
    else
      render_error(result.errors.to_h, status: :bad_request)
    end
  end
```

What did I missed here?

**[Edit]**

```
# Gemfile.lock
dry-validation (1.10.0)
```

I've got also the `initializers/dry_validator.rb`:

```
require 'dry/validation'

Dry::Validation.load_extensions(:monads)
```

parent class `ApplicationService` is here:

```
class ApplicationService < Dry::Validation::Contract
  def self.call(*args)
    new.call(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: You might have to provide a bit more context because I cannot recreate your issue based on this post [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/CharmingFrugalTruetype#main.rb). Can you tell me what version of `dry-validation` you are using?

Comment: @engineersmnky question updated. But you're facing the same issue - you've pass the param of `return_url` but the validator shows you an error of: `{:sdd_setup_request=>{:return_url=>["is missing"]}}`

Comment: No I did not pass it in the second call and thus the error as expected. Everything is working as it should in the code. Updated using your additions.

Comment: I've no idea, copy/paste all of your code and still getting `sdd_setup_request is missing` for a valid JSON. I'm using postman to make requests to my app

Comment: What does your postman request look like specifically. Also might want to print out what `params` looks like in the controller. Chances are likely that your request is wrapped in some fashion and the `sdd_setup_request` key is not at the top level.

Comment: It's a POST request with JSON body, No Auth, Headers with Content-Type: application/json, Accept */* - and that's it, super basic as you see.

Comment: @engineersmnky Mother of perl I've got it! If I passed `request.params` instead of  `params` to the validator call (`SddRequestValidator.call(request.params)` it will work like a charm. No idea why, I guess it's related with some key formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an issue but if you are using the rails `params` method or if you are using strong parameters then call `.to_h` on it before passing params to validation.

For example if you have below method

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

Pass above params like this: `result = UserSchema::CreateParams.call(user_params.to_h)`